# Do they support transactions for single DDL and DML SQL statement regardless of Storage Engine type?

Tags: google-bigquery

1. Does single DML SQL statement transaction depend on storage type? In other words, are transactions supported for all the storage types like Cloud Storage or Google Drive or Bigtable or Cloud SQL? Do they support transactions for tables on Cloud Storage (which is my case)?
2. Do they support transactions for DDL statements (CREATE, DROP, ALTER) in BigQuery regardless of storage engine type? Thank you for your kind answer in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Storage, Google Drive,Bigtable, Cloud SQL are external tables, so with BigQuery we can only query the data, not any other DML operations are possible.
[https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources\](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources%5C)
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language

BigQuery supports DDL statements for native and external BigQuery tables, but it cannot do run DDL statements in the external resources(Cloud Storage, Google Drive,Bigtable, Cloud SQL).
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#running_ddl_statements

Comment: Do they support single DDL SQL statement transaction in BigQuery? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language indicates that they support single DML SQL statement transaction but DDL page does not mention transaction at all. Thank you for your kind reply in advance.